# Swift animation - Touchdown doesn't work well

Tags: swift, animation, swift3, view, touch-up-inside

I'm trying to create de same effect than the app "Music" :

[image]
[image]

When I click on a button, there is a view behind and when the button is not focused anymore, the view is hidden. I do this with TouchUpInside and TouchDown funcs.

```
    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
         self.backgroundMoreView.alpha = 0.0
         self.backgroundMoreView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:
            1.2, y: 1.2)
         sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
      }) { (_) in
         self.backgroundMoreView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
         }
   }


   @IBAction func unpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
         self.backgroundMoreView.alpha = 0.3
         sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y:
            0.8)
      }
   }
```

The problem is that, when I click and hold focus, and then I swipe out of the button, the function unpressed() is not called and the button stay "focused".

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe touchesEnded() ?

Comment: There is no touchesEnded function in the storyboard :/ Do you mean Touch Cancel ?

Comment: No, I mean function in your VC touchesEnded

Comment: Or implement one more function touchUpOutside with the some code as in the touchUpInside

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(unpressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpOutside)
```

Or connect it using storyboard to the same action (unpressed) with `touchUpOutside`

Comment: It doesn't fire the action?

Comment: Nope :/ Nothing happened